# aws Backup job failed because the lifecycle is outside the valid range for backup vault

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, backup

I'm working on an AWS Backup Plan and successful to deploy the same, however while adding an extra Backup Vault attributes/settings like `LockConfiguration` it reports and issue on the console `Backup job failed because the lifecycle is outside the valid range for backup vault.` which i'm not able to get it, I see the AWS Backup documentation is not updated well.

While looking for the the error around goggling i didn't find any clue.

Below is the cloudformation code which i'm using :

**Code:** [cloudformation](/questions/tagged/cloudformation)

```
  BackupsVault:
    Type: "AWS::Backup::BackupVault"
    Properties:
      BackupVaultName: MyVault
      LockConfiguration:
        ChangeableForDays: 3
        MinRetentionDays: 4
        MaxRetentionDays: 5

  BackupPlan:
    Type: "AWS::Backup::BackupPlan"
    Properties:
      BackupPlan:
        BackupPlanName: !Ref myBackupPlan
        BackupPlanRule:
          -
            RuleName: !Ref MyFsxRule
            TargetBackupVault: !Ref BackupsVault
            ScheduleExpression: "cron(45 13 ? * * *)"
            Lifecycle:
              DeleteAfterDays: 21
    DependsOn: BackupsVault
```

**Error:**

Backup job failed because the lifecycle is outside the valid range for backup vault.

[image]

Is there anything which is conflicting between `BackupVAlt` and `backupPlan` ? , Please see if you guys already know about this and can hint me to the right direction.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am getting the same error while using Aurora Serverless v2.

Comment: @Johnny5,  to my case i found the  Errror `Backup job failed because the lifecycle is outside the valid range for backup vault` is caused due to The `MinRetentionDays` and `MaxRetentionDays` parameters.we need to specify the minimum and maximum allowed days that the recovery point can be retained in the vault. If the job's retention period is shorter than that minimum retention period, then the vault fails that backup job or If the job's retention period is longer than that maximum retention period, then also the vault fails the backup .

Comment: Therefore the lifecycle setting in your backup plans need to be within the range as per the vault lock configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Vaultlock retention period, and verify whether it is less than your backup retention

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others about `MaxRetentionDays` and `DeleteAfterDays`, i just combined that into a config file with some comments

Your Backup Plan do not exceed the valid range specified in the `LockConfiguration`. In your provided code, you have set `DeleteAfterDays: 21` in your Backup Plan's Lifecycle, which exceeds the range defined in the LockConfiguration.

Here's how you can adjust your CloudFormation code:

```
BackupsVault:
  Type: "AWS::Backup::BackupVault"
  Properties:
    BackupVaultName: MyVault
    LockConfiguration:
      ChangeableForDays: 3
      MinRetentionDays: 4
      MaxRetentionDays: 21  # Adjust the MaxRetentionDays to match your desired retention

BackupPlan:
  Type: "AWS::Backup::BackupPlan"
  Properties:
    BackupPlan:
      BackupPlanName: !Ref myBackupPlan
      BackupPlanRule:
        -
          RuleName: !Ref MyFsxRule
          TargetBackupVault: !Ref BackupsVault
          ScheduleExpression: "cron(45 13 ? * * *)"
          Lifecycle:
            DeleteAfterDays: 21  # Make sure this value aligns with MaxRetentionDays
DependsOn: BackupsVault
```